# Why do I get an error when pinging a windows computer by HOSTNAME from Linux Unbutu 20.04?

Tags: windows, ping, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Hyper-V Linx Ubuntu 20.04 VM
I'm trying to ping a windows box in my domain via it's HOSTHAME.

I've followed some threads with this suggested fix:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind
```

I then updated /etc/nsswitch.conf to contain the following line:

```
hosts:          files dns wins
```

Now when I attempt to ping the windows machine by HOSTNAME, I get the following error:

```
ping SOMESERVER
ping:SOMESERVER: Name or Service not found
```

What do I need to do in order to get this to work?
Are there additional configuration changes that I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS servers / your DNS Suffix. You have have to ping the FQDN of the machine

Comment: sorry, not entirely sure what you mean. Can you pls explain more? Thx

Comment: @jstuart-tech But you __do__ know what DNS ist, right?